# error : Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2

Getting this message when I am trying to save some fields' information for a custom form, this has happened I think when I have upgraded to Magento 2.3, so this problem still happens also for the deployment instance not just in my local

can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

please use incognito mode, if issue exists, clear cache give permissions and then try.